# Car fuel level sensor remotely monitoring

Tags: sensors, wifi, mobile-applications

[Car fuel level sensor](https://www.google.com/search?q=car%20fuel%20level%20sensor&oq=Automobilefuel%20leve&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCAgCEAAYFhgeMgYIABBFGDkyCggBEAAYDxgWGB4yCAgCEAAYFhgeMggIAxAAGBYYHjIICAQQABgWGB4yCAgFEAAYFhgeMggIBhAAGBYYHjIKCAcQABgPGBYYHjIICAgQABgWGB4yDQgJEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgKEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgLEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgMEAAYhgMYgAQYigUyDQgNEAAYhgMYgAQYigXSAQkxMTkwNGowajGoAgCwAgA&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Car fuel level monitoring is implemented and viewed on the dashboard with assistance of fuel level sensor inside the Automobile.

Is it possible to remotely monitor a running automobile's fuel level with assistance of Smartphone apps,WI-FI, Internet of Things (IOT)?

If yes, how?

If no, why?

Comment: why would it not be possible?  ... research the fuel level sensors and how they work ... determine what electrical quantity they  transmit ... then determine how that quantity can be monitored with a microcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible within the limits that exists in the vehicle network ecosystem. Like one of the answer suggested you can plug a OBD2 reader and connect with it to get the readings.

This has it's limitations though. The vehicle come with fuel level sensors but the values are not always broadcasted or made available to the BCM (body control module) with which these OBD readers communicate. The ability to be able to read such data gets a little complicated. You will ideally have to tap into the CAN network directly from the OBD2 port (pin 6 & 14) and reverse engineer the function address (jargon for vehicle CAN communication) that the fuel level is being mapped to inside this particular vehicle network. And to your surprise, these IDs are not standard across different manufactures or models. So, it becomes a long journey of reverse engineering. But assuming, if you are able to do that - then it is just a matter of writing a CAN payload targeting the function address to get the value in response.

[image]

Comment: This feels like it's very specific to a certain brand/model of car. Not every brand will report fuel levels to the BCM. As a matter of fact, that seems quite an odd place for it to go instead of the Engine Control Unit. I also find it hard to believe that any car wouldn't report out fuel tank level via OBD II. I have software that will allow me to _set_ various features on my car, but I can read the settings without it.

Comment: The external OBD readers do not interact with ECM (atleast not off the shelf bluetooth dongles) directly. There are sophisticated readers which tap into the CAN network directly and talk to targeted ECUs with their specific addresses to provide a much richer feature set.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you reinvent technology.  You can use the OBD2 port on your car.  Plug something like this in.  As an example [OBD-II Engine Code Reader with Bluetooth® Technology](https://www.jaycar.co.nz/obd-ii-engine-code-reader-with-bluetooth-technology/p/PP2145).

- Then you can select from a number of apps for your phone, some include heads up display that you can customise.  I have used Torque in the past.
- If you dont want to use an existing app, then write your own using the OBD2 port.

[image]